# ExpandabeListview Custom ID

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Can you set a custom id to a group and child? I have my own id's I need to use.
So each group has its own id and i child its own id ?

I know with a ListView adapter you can do this :

```
@Override
public HashMap getItem(int position) {
    return (HashMap) mItems.get(position);
}
```

Once a user selects or expands a group, I need to keep track of the expanded ones so I can send this data back to a web server api.

Comment: yeah you can use... child and groups are our own custom designs . so we can use our id's

Comment: have a look at this . http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/03/simple-expandable-list-view.html?view=sidebar

Comment: Shweet, got it like this:  Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    group.getID();